# numpy.load() is not loading

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I would like to save my trained parameters, so I can load them and use them later. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me, here is my code:

```py
import os.path

def save(parameters):
    #parameters have weights and biases
    L = len(parameters)//2
    W = {}
    b = {}
    for l in range(1,L):
        W["W" + str(l)] = parameters["W" + str(l)]
        b["b" + str(l)] = parameters["b" + str(l)]
    print(W)
    num = 1
    while os.path.isfile('trainedData/weights{}.npy'.format(num)):
        num += 1 
    else:
        np.save('trainedData/weights{}.npy'.format(num), W)

    num = 1
    while os.path.isfile('trainedData/biases{}.npy'.format(num)):
        num += 1
    else:
        np.save('trainedData/biases{}.npy'.format(num), b)
```

```py
save(parameters)
#PRINT(W) IS CORRECTLY PRINTING WEIGHTS
```

```py
def load(num):
    W = np.load('trainedData/weights{}.npy'.format(num), allow_pickle=True)
    b = np.load('trainedData/biases{}.npy'.format(num), allow_pickle=True)
    print(W)
```

```py
load(1)
```

is going to print just this:

```py
{}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: I could copy and paste your code and run without any problem

Comment: Thanks for the help!. After restarting Jupyter Notebook, newer saves started to work correctly